# How to change the "Account already exists" error in Woocommerce on checkout, into a login box?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, code-snippets

Woocommerce checkout throws an error "An account is already registered with your email address", when you did not log in before checkout.

This is so clumsy. What I want in this case is to immediately show a popup with a login box, with the email address already populated.

It looks a little like this question: [Woocommerce: Override login required for existing email. Add order to user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54702729/woocommerce-override-login-required-for-existing-email-add-order-to-user-accou)

But it is different.

I can't find anything that comes close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked for a solution as well.  The closest I have found is the plugin linked below.

What I like is that when an email is added it will recognize if they are a past customer and automatically reveals a password input box underneath the email box.  https://www.checkoutwc.com

This article describes more of what I mean under Login Lookup heading:  https://oceanwp.org/blog/optimizing-your-woocommerce-checkout-page-with-checkout-for-woocommerce/

I have been testing it and so far I am happy with it.  I signed up for the monthly subscription and will see if it helps increase sales.  We get a 7-day free trial to play with it.

I also agree that Woo's solution is a little clumsy.  :)

Best of luck! :)

Comment: This is a good solution, however the pricing is not one of my favorites (a monthly 15 USD). But, they did a great job, so I will definitely try it. Thanks!

Comment: I thought the same thing.  But, since it is the only solution I could find I had decided it would be worth the try.  If it helps increase sales and make the checkout process smoother, it may be well worth the cost.  

Only one way to find out.  Best of luck. :)